# boolean subtract DeprecationWarning

Tags: python, numpy, duck-typing

I recently upgraded to numpy 1.9dev.
(For improved OpenBlas support).

I have some code that does `x-y` 
Where `x` and `y` are samples from a probability distribution.
If the distribution is Bernoulli, then they are boolean.
If the distribution is Gaussian, then they are floats.

where depending on the path followed `x` and `y`
might be bools or floats.
I don't have to care as python has duck-typing.
If it can subtract then it is a valid value for `x` and `y`

I get this warning:

> DeprecationWarning: numpy boolean subtract (the binary `-` operator)
>   is deprecated, use the bitwise_xor (the `^` operator) or the
>   logical_xor function instead.

I have made the warning go away, by casting it to always be a float.
This may be a good thing since it makes the code more consistent at a lower level.
(Not sold on that as a good thing).

What is the correct action to be taking?
I can't use boolean or bitwise xor as when `x` and `y` are floats this will break.
It would be ugly to make the code branch on the type of `x` and `y`.

Comment: What should, in your mind, `False - True` be?

Comment: Jamie: good point. Never quiet though that through.
 The answer is that my expectation is -1.
And this indicated that my data is probably better represented as floats (or ints).

Comment: @Jamie I have added more details to my question. Perhaps you might like to make an answer explaining that the basic premise that you could subtract boolean is nonsense.

Comment: You could use `np.subtract(a, b, dtype=np.float)`. math operations on bool map to logical operations and not map to 1 and zero like C does. The only exception I know of is sum() which does an implicit cast to an integer

Comment: This is annoying because for scipy sparse matrices it is still `-` not `^`

Comment: But I have to agree that you would have to read `a-b` as `a+(-b)` meaning `a or not b`, which would be something else than what currently happens in subtracting boolean sparse matrices. XOR is `(a and not(b)) or (not(a) and b)`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

maybe you should do:

```
x=x.astype(numpy.float32)
y=y.astype(numpy.float32)
```

then

```
x - y
```

at least, it works on my case.

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution:

```
z = (x.astype(np.float32) - y.astype(np.float32)).astype(np.bool)
```