# Subtracting booleans obtained from numpy variables results in TypeError

Tags: python, numpy

I have trouble understanding this weird behaviour while using numpy variable-

```
import numpy as np
from operator import lt,gt
val = lt(np.float64(0.8514),0) - gt(np.float(0.8514),0)
```

This fails with the following error-

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-ddc655dbbe89> in <module>()
      1 from operator import lt,gt
----> 2 val = lt(np.float64(0.8514),0) - gt(np.float(0.8514),0)

TypeError: numpy boolean subtract, the `-` operator, is deprecated, use the bitwise_xor, the `^` operator, or the logical_xor function instead.
```

This should not happen as the output of lt and gt is a boolean variable. The following snippets both work without a hitch-

```
from operator import lt,gt
import numpy as np
val = True - False
val = lt(float(np.float64(0.8514)),0) - gt(float(np.float(0.8514)),0)
```

I don't understand what's the issue being when the input is a numpy variable. The above code was executed in Python-2.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216210/boolean-subtract-deprecationwarning

Answer (score 1):

As the error message indicates, the `-` operator is deprecated. Just use the `^` operator for logical operations instead.

```
import numpy as np
from operator import lt, gt

exp1 = lt(np.float64(0.8514), 0)
exp2 = gt(np.float64(0.8514), 0)

val = exp1 ^ exp2
print(val) # True
```

I don't get the error message if I use Python 3 and `val = exp1 - exp2` also works. So you may consider using Python 3 instead of Python 2.

If you, for some reason, don't want to perform logical operations, you can cast `exp1` and `exp2` to `float` or `int`:

```
import numpy as np
from operator import lt, gt

exp1 = lt(np.float64(0.8514), 0)
exp2 = gt(np.float64(0.8514), 0)

val = int(exp1) - int(exp2)
print(val) # -1

val = float(exp1) - float(exp2)
print(val) # -1.0
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I know how to fix the issue. My question was lt,gt functions return boolean output and then I am trying to subtract them. This should work irrespective of what was input to those functions.

Comment: @DishankAgrawal According to the error message, it seems to me that the operator `-` is just no longer supported. That means, that the `-` operator is not defined for boolean operations. In C++ terms, the minus operator is not overloaded to work for boolean operations as well.